# Fluid images with height property set in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a site with a fluid layout, using percentages for all the widths and margins and such. I'd like to use the `img { max-width: 100% }` trick to make the images fluid as well, but I've run into a bit of a problem.

I'm using [embedagram](https://github.com/h0ke/jquery-embedagram) to grab the latest instagram photo from an account and display it at 500 x 500 px. This works fine, but the way it does this is to toss the dimensions directly into the HTML like so:

```
<img src=" " title=" " width="500" height="500" border="0" align="absmiddle">
```

So, `max-width` still works, but the image no longer scales proportionally - it just squishes and gets distorted. `max-height: 100%` doesn't help. I'm having a tough time understanding the instagram API documentation and how that would translate to javascript, otherwise I'd probably scrap embedagram and just do it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `height: auto` to your style declaration:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VDB7A/

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix would be to style the dimensions of the image with CSS using the !important directive:

```
img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;        
}
```

I believe that's the only way you're going to get your css to take precedence over the attribute settings in the markup.

A cleaner solution may be to eliminate the attributes altogether, but that would involve some scripting - either modifying the plugin to not include them in the first place -or- reset them after they've been set.

Comment: This is not true. Only the `style="..."` attribute requires `!important` to override it.